# How to change class style text "Nonaktif" in table on Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter

I want to change badge color text "Nonaktif" to red,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxt7n.png)

this my td:

```
<tr>
  <td><?php echo $no++ ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $bk->kode_kas?></td>
  <td><?php echo $bk->nama_kas?></td>
  <td><?php echo "Rp. ".number_format($bk->saldo_kas,0,',','.')?></td>
  <td><h5><span id="status" class="badge badge-pill badge-success"><?php echo $bk->status_kas?></span></h5></td>
  <td><?php echo $bk->ket_kas?></td>
```

Comment: where is that text in your code?

Comment: `<span id="status" class="badge badge-pill badge-<?= $bk->status_kas == 'Nonaktif' ? 'danger' : 'success'>">`

Comment: Your question is a bit vague which makes it hard to help :)
Please elaborate more.
Color is related to css (do you have a css file or using any client-side framework).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a small condition on your class attribute like that:

```
<h5><span id="status" class="badge badge-pill <?= $bk->status_kas == 'Nonaktif' ? 'badge-info': 'badge-success'; ?>"><?= $bk->status_kas ?></span></h5>
```